# How to dynamically set text size of all items in a list view based on database value in Android?

Tags: android, listview, text-size

I'm trying to allow the user to set the font size in an app that uses ListViews.  How do I get the font-size from a database and use it to set the size of text in a listview?

Edit: examples would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the fontsize from database using select query.
2. set the fontsize of textview in listview at your listview;s getview method with textview.setTextSize(int,float);

Answer (score 1):

For accessing a database please check an example here: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

In order to change the text size of the textview of a listview, you should set this font size in the getView() of the listview's adapter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy,**first** you make sure that you can receive textSize from database.**second** you must find the text from listview item,in method ***OnItemClick()*** you can get the view which clicked, and then use ***View.findviewbyid()*** to find out which view you want set the textsize,then use ***getText()*** method to receive text what you want to change, in the end you maybe call method ***notifyDataSetChanged()***.